# How to run producer and consumer console on windows

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

i created an demo project to check the functionality of **kafka with spring boot**.
i successfully created this demo. but when i go to run this project then producer receives msg but **consumer giving me warning in the console**.
i don't understanding why this is giving me warning, please someone help me to resolved this.
also this warning is shown infinity time.

Here is my **application.yml** code

```
spring:
   kafka:
     consumer:
        bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
        group-id: group_id
        auto-offset-reset: earliest
        key-deserializer: 
        org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        value-deserializer: 
        org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
     producer:
        bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
        key-serializer: 
        org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        value-serializer: 
        org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

Here is my **Producer.java**

```
package com.kafkaexample.engine;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Producer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Producer.class);
    private static final String TOPIC = "users";

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        logger.info(String.format("#### -> Producing message -> %s", message));
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, message);
    }
}
```

Here is my **Consumer.java**

```
package com.kafkaexample.engine;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.IOException;

@Service
public class Consumer {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Consumer.class);

    @KafkaListener(topics = "users", groupId = "group_id")
    public void consume(String message) throws IOException {
        logger.info(String.format("#### -> Consumed message -> %s", message));
    }
}
```

Here is my **Controller**

```
package com.kafkaexample.controller;

import com.kafkaexample.engine.Producer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/kafka")
public class KafkaController {

    private final Producer producer;

    @Autowired
    KafkaController(Producer producer) {
        this.producer = producer;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/publish")
    public void sendMessageToKafkaTopic(@RequestParam("message") String message) {
        this.producer.sendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Here is the console of project when i run the application

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.5\lib\idea_rt.jar=51889:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.5\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\tecor\Lugbee_data\Lugbee\lugbee_notification\kafkaWithSpringBoot\target\classes;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.11.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.11.2\log4j-api-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.26\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.26.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.23\snakeyaml-1.23.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-json-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.8\jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.8\jackson-core-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.8\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.8\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.8\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.17\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.17\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.17.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.17\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.16.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.16.Final.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.4\classmate-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\kafka\spring-kafka\2.2.5.RELEASE\spring-kafka-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-messaging\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-messaging-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\retry\spring-retry\1.2.4.RELEASE\spring-retry-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\apache\kafka\kafka-clients\2.0.1\kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\lz4\lz4-java\1.4.1\lz4-java-1.4.1.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\xerial\snappy\snappy-java\1.1.7.1\snappy-java-1.1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-test\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-test-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-test\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-test-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-test-autoconfigure\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\com\jayway\jsonpath\json-path\2.4.0\json-path-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\2.3\json-smart-2.3.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\net\minidev\accessors-smart\1.2\accessors-smart-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\5.0.4\asm-5.0.4.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\assertj\assertj-core\3.11.1\assertj-core-3.11.1.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-core\2.23.4\mockito-core-2.23.4.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.9.3\byte-buddy-1.9.3.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy-agent\1.9.3\byte-buddy-agent-1.9.3.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\2.6\objenesis-2.6.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-library\1.3\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\skyscreamer\jsonassert\1.5.0\jsonassert-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\external\google\android-json\0.0.20131108.vaadin1\android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shree\.m2\repository\org\xmlunit\xmlunit-core\2.6.2\xmlunit-core-2.6.2.jar" com.kafkaexample.SpringBootWithKafkaApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)

2019-06-19 18:27:44.241  INFO 10268 --- [           main] c.k.SpringBootWithKafkaApplication       : Starting SpringBootWithKafkaApplication on DESKTOP-4IEB7U7 with PID 10268 (D:\tecor\Lugbee_data\Lugbee\lugbee_notification\kafkaWithSpringBoot\target\classes started by Shree in D:\tecor\Lugbee_data\Lugbee\lugbee_notification\kafkaWithSpringBoot)
2019-06-19 18:27:44.245  INFO 10268 --- [           main] c.k.SpringBootWithKafkaApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-06-19 18:27:46.280  INFO 10268 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaBootstrapConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9e6cbd54] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-06-19 18:27:48.100  INFO 10268 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-06-19 18:27:48.199  INFO 10268 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-06-19 18:27:48.199  INFO 10268 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.17]
2019-06-19 18:27:48.791  INFO 10268 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-06-19 18:27:48.791  INFO 10268 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4443 ms
2019-06-19 18:27:49.430  INFO 10268 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-06-19 18:27:50.080  INFO 10268 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = true
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = group_id
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

2019-06-19 18:27:50.257  INFO 10268 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version : 2.0.1
2019-06-19 18:27:50.257  INFO 10268 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId : fa14705e51bd2ce5
2019-06-19 18:27:50.504  INFO 10268 --- [           main] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : Cluster ID: 8MB-usFlR12orAsTFzBlng
2019-06-19 18:27:50.524  INFO 10268 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = true
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = group_id
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

2019-06-19 18:27:50.534  INFO 10268 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version : 2.0.1
2019-06-19 18:27:50.534  INFO 10268 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId : fa14705e51bd2ce5
2019-06-19 18:27:50.540  INFO 10268 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService
2019-06-19 18:27:50.599  WARN 10268 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=group_id] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [users-0]
2019-06-19 18:27:50.600  INFO 10268 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : Cluster ID: 8MB-usFlR12orAsTFzBlng
2019-06-19 18:27:50.628  INFO 10268 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-06-19 18:27:50.633  INFO 10268 --- [           main] c.k.SpringBootWithKafkaApplication       : Started SpringBootWithKafkaApplication in 7.171 seconds (JVM running for 7.869)
-------------

service started

-------------
2019-06-19 18:27:50.706  WARN 10268 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=group_id] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [users-0]
```

```
2019-06-19 18:27:50.706  WARN 10268 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=group_id] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [users-0]
```

-> this log shown infinity time. also when i run producer and consumer through window console using the cmd command then also it is giving me the same warning in consumer console.

i followed this link
[here is link which i followed to create topic, run producer and consumer in cmd](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart)

command of creating topic and run producer is successfully run but when i run consumer then it shown me about mention warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is occurring because your are using in-built zookeeper if you setup zookeeper separately then your problem will solved. for setting up zookeeper separately do the following:

Download ZooKeeper from [http://zookeeper.apache.org/releases.html](http://%20https://zookeeper.apache.org/releases.html)

1. ZooKeeper Installation

   1. Go to your ZooKeeper config directory. For me its C:\zookeeper-3.4.7\conf
   2. Rename file “zoo_sample.cfg” to “zoo.cfg”
   3. Open zoo.cfg in any text editor, like Notepad; I prefer Notepad++.
   4. Find and edit dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper to :\zookeeper-3.4.7\data
   5. Add an entry in the System Environment Variables as we did for Java.

   a. Add ZOOKEEPER_HOME = C:\zookeeper-3.4.7 to the System Variables.

   b. Edit the System Variable named “Path” and add ;%ZOOKEEPER_HOME%\bin;

   6. You can change the default Zookeeper port in zoo.cfg file (Default port 2181).
   7. Run ZooKeeper by opening a new cmd and type zkserver.

note: run zkserver command in cmd after going into bin directory.

after this zookeeper server is started successfully, now you will be face no error in future.